# How to use index to assign address and formula to arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

How to assign address and formula to arrays?

For example

```
import numpy as np
import math
from numpy import matrix
y = np.matrix( [y,y,y],[ -2,0,3]])
```

I want to call `y(i=0 j)   for j in range(3)` or assign it `f(x)=2x+5  for x in range(3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't start with that first line, since `y` is not defined before your use of it:

```py
np.matrix([y, y, y], [-2, 0, 3]])  # interpreter says "what is y?"
```

So instead, start with your function.  If you want to call your function `f(x) = 2*x + 5` on several values, you must define it first:

```py
def f(x):
    return 2*x + 5
```

Then you can call it on all the values at once, assuming you make an array for input:

```py
xs = np.arange(3)  # -> array([0, 1, 2])
f(xs)              # -> array([5, 7, 9])
```

Now, you can build `y` as such:

```py
y = np.matrix([f(xs), [-2, 0, 3]])
# matrix([[ 5,  7,  9],
#         [-2,  0,  3]])
```

Or, you can build `y` first, then fill it later:

```py
y = np.matrix([[0, 0, 0], [-2, 0, 3]])
y[0, :] = f(xs)  # `0` means first row, `:` means all columns
print y
# matrix([[ 5,  7,  9],
#         [-2,  0,  3]])
```